# How to fix 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I have this error a couple of days ago. There are several similar questions but no answer solved my problem.

It happens when I run `npm run start`, after running `npm run build`

Why does `npm run start` run files with a `.ts` extension like `ormconfig.ts`? Is it correct behavior? Shouldn't `ormconfig.js` run?

- **Full error message**

**C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\ormconfig.ts:1**

***import { Booking } from "./src/entities/Booking"***

***SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module***
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at ConnectionOptionsReader. (C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\typeorm\connection\ConnectionOptionsReader.js:120:46)
at step (C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27)
at Object.next (C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57)
at C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:117:75
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:16)
at ConnectionOptionsReader.load (C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\typeorm\connection\ConnectionOptionsReader.js:92:38)
at ConnectionOptionsReader. (C:\Users\franc\Code\f5\server\node_modules\typeorm\connection\ConnectionOptionsReader.js:34:55)

- **package.json**

[image]

- **tsconfig.json**

[image]

- **Project strcture**

[image]

**PS:** *this is my first question on the platform, if there is missing data tell me! and sorry for my english :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `ormconfig.ts` to your `src` folder (change imports if necessary), and add the `include` after `compilerOptions` to include everything in the `src`. It's also a good idea to use `exclude` node_modules and tests:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests"]
}
```

It might be because TypeScript is including ormconfig.ts in the compilation output: as you can see in the build folder there is an index.js and ormconfig.js AND duplicate `src` folder.